# Sitecore 8.2: Rich Text editor's Hyperlink Manager giving error

Tags: sitecore-client

I have Sitecore 8.2 site and  i am adding my item's content in Rich Text Editor. When i click on Hyper link manager, it's giving an error in popup:

[image]

Comment: Can you verify if  IgnoreUrlPrefixes settings was override in your config file?  can you compare this setting with a clean Sitecore solution?

Comment: I have updated my website from sitecore 8.0 to sitecore 8.2 and facing the same issue. The above mentioned lines are there in web.config. What melse can be done to resolve the issue

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you have these entries in web.config ( which comes by default)

```
    <add name="Telerik_Web_UI_DialogHandler_aspx" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" path="Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler.aspx" type="Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler" />
  <add name="Telerik_Web_UI_SpellCheckHandler_axd" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" path="Telerik.Web.UI.SpellCheckHandler.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.SpellCheckHandler" />
  <add name="Telerik_Web_UI_WebResource_axd" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" path="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource" />
```

More Information:

Error Message from Telerik*.dll ( using ILSPY)
[image]

Click action from browser:
[image]